# Why Operator overloading behaves so strange

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Hello Friend the output of the below program is so strange. I am not getting the reason.[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class xyz
{
    private:
    int ab, cd;
    public:
    xyz()
    {

    }
    xyz(int i, int j)
    {
        ab = i;
        cd = j;

    }
    xyz operator+(xyz);
    void show()
    {
        cout << ab << " ....  "<< cd;
    }

};
xyz xyz :: operator +(xyz ob)
{
    xyz temp;
    temp.ab = ab + temp.ab;
    temp.cd = cd + temp.cd;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
   // xyz xy, yz;

   xyz xy(2, 3);
   xyz yz(4, 5);
    xy = xy + yz;

    xy.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger? Or are **we** the debugger?

Comment: @Neal:Yes I did debug the code particularly temp.ab = ab + temp.ab;
    temp.cd = cd + temp.cd; the code behaves strange

Comment: In addition to the solutions below I would also initialise the member variables in the default constructor:

xyz() : ab(0),cd(0) {}

Comment: The real question is, why did it take 0.343 seconds to run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy&paste error?

This

```
temp.ab = ab + temp.ab;
temp.cd = cd + temp.cd;
```

should be

```
temp.ab = ab + ob.ab;
temp.cd = cd + ob.cd;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `operator+()`, the `xyz temp;` is uninitialised and contains whatever garbage happened to be in that location.

Answer (score 3):

```
xyz xyz :: operator +(xyz ob)
```

You don't use the ob object whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The temp object was just created initialized with random values and codeis just adding to it.

```
xyz xyz :: operator +(xyz ob)
{
xyz temp;
temp.ab = ab + ob.ab;
temp.cd = cd + ob.cd;
return temp;
}
```

output:

6..8